# Powershell not showing git branch name in all directories

Tags: git, powershell

This is my powershell profile:

```
function Write-BranchName () {
    try {
        $branch = git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD

        if ($branch -eq "HEAD") {
            # we're probably in detached HEAD state, so print the SHA
            $branch = git rev-parse --short HEAD
            Write-Host " git:($branch)" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "red"
        }
        else {
            # we're on an actual branch, so print it
            Write-Host " git:($branch)" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "magenta"
        }
    } catch {
        # we'll end up here if we're in a newly initiated git repo
        Write-Host " (no branches yet)" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "yellow"
    }
}

function prompt {
    $base = "PS "
    $path = "$($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)"
    $userPrompt = "$(' >>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "

    Write-Host "`n$base" -NoNewline

    if (Test-Path .git) {
        Write-Host $path -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "cyan" 
        Write-BranchName
    }
    else {
        # we're not in a repo so don't bother displaying branch name/sha
        Write-Host $path -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "cyan"
    }

    return $userPrompt 
}
```

And this is my project directory:

```
|
|--API
|--Application
|--client-app
|--Domain
|--Infrastructure
|--Persistence
|--Reactivities.sln
```

Currently git branch is showed perfectly as RefreshTokens

```
PS Reactivities git:(RefreshTokens) >>
```

But when I change directory to API directory for example, git branch is NOT showed!?

```
PS Reactivities\API >>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Write-BranchName` is called `if (Test-Path .git)`. There is no `.git` in `API` apparently.

Try `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to test if the current path is inside a git repository and get the repository's path.

I don't know about Powershell script, but I think you could call `Write-BranchName` without `if..else...`. If the current path is not inside a git repository, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` would raise an error or an exception.

Comment: Thanks. your answered worked. no need for  ```if...else...```